# Selectors in Ionic 3 / Angular 4

Tags: ionic2

Good day, as you know in Ionic 2 / Angular 2 it was possible to use the selector of one component in another. Please tell me how it can be done on Ionic 3 / Angular 4

Comment: there is no change there ...

Comment: I have selector Component and his selector "page-news". So when i call it in Component Weather I have the error like that  Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: 'page-weather' is not a known element: 1. If 'page-weather' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 'page-weather' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: What i do wrong?

Comment: you will have to [edit] the question and provide code.. Please read [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

from the error you post, I think you want to use "page-weather" in the component of "page-news", if these two component belongs to different modules, then you should import the "page-weather" module to the "page-news" module, like the following:

```
import {WeatherModule} from '../your component's path';
@NgModule({
  imports: [WeatchModule]
})
export class NewsModule {}
```

then you can use "page-weather" in the "page-news" template like this:

```
<page-weather></page-weather>
```

hope this can help you!